# Pros/Cons of not using a class in a file holding only constants?

Tags: python

If a .py file will hold only constants, is it advantageous to use a class or is it more correct to simply put the constants in the file?

```
from collections import namedtuple


    class Teste(object):

        Point = namedtuple('Point', ['x', 'y'])
        center = Point(0,0)
```

Or just:

```
from collections import namedtuple


Point = namedtuple('Point', ['x', 'y'])
center = Point(0,0)
```

Comment: Why would you use a class here at all?

Comment: Well, if it's not a class or a type what is it then? Simply an object? Can I be sure a long list of constant perhaps using `dict()` and `set()` will get initialized without `__new__(cls)`? And what would I gain in this case versus going for a `@staticmethod` class?

Comment: It sounds like you are coming from Java; `Point` itself is a type, `center` is an instance of that type, and both are just objects that live in the global namespace of the module. `Teste` is just an unnecessary wrapper around `Point` and `center`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a class then you will have to instantiate this class before you use the variables, whereas if you just place the variables in the file, they will be loaded into memory whenever you import that file into your main program.

I generally will use classes to hold variables, because it can provide more flexibility on when to instantiate them (in **init**, global assignment, or through custom builder methods). It also allows you to make multiple instances of the class, which seems like it could be useful in your case (making points), though I don't know what then rest of your project looks like.

The main time I will use variables straight in the file is when creating a config file. These would be variable that I know I will never alter within the project, and I can import these variables and refer to them directly.

Let me know if there's anything you'd like me to elaborate on.

Comment: I agree the class has no real purpose, but it's not clear if by "instantiate" you mean the `class` object itself needs to be created (which is true and happens immediately on import), or that an instance of the class needs to be created (which is not true).

Comment: You guys are right, if I don't need a custom method no need for a class.

Comment: @chepner Well in order to access the class variables, which is what the question here is about, you need to instantiate the class, correct?

Comment: No; the class exists, and you can access the two *class* attributes directly from the class. You would need to instantiate it to access *instance* attributes.